# MySQL querying in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to write an app that will check whether or not an webpage has changed.
I'm using NodeJs mysql because I'm familiar with them.

So at the moment, I have the problem that my query is too 'slow', so my function will not return true, even though it should. Can I force my app to wait for the query somehow?

Edit:

```
 checkEntry(webpage, callback) {

    var oldPage;

    this.mysql.query('SELECT OldWebpagecol FROM Web_Scraping.OldWebpage WHERE idOldWebpage = 15',  (err, rows) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        oldPage = rows[0].OldWebpagecol;

        if (webpage === oldPage) {
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    })
}
```

Comment: Tip: Use Promises if you can, via `async` and `await` is even better. Also consider using a more abstract layer like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) versus the `mysql` driver.

Comment: Note: The `return` here in the callback function doesn't do anything, it's ignored. You need to do `callback(null, webpage === oldPage)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await when you make a request.

For example,

```
(async () => {
  let response = await fetch(‘/api/users’);
})();
```

Comment: But I do not fetch from an api, I make a mysql query? So how would that look?

Comment: Write your mysql query intead of api call. It is not hard, just write async at the beginning of the function and write await at the begining of the mysql query execution.

Comment: If you put some code, i can help you much.

Comment: I have posted my query now